# cropping UIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, quartz-2d

I have 4 points on an image (not perfectly a rectangle, just a 4 point polygon). For example:

[image]

I want to extract the image bounded by the 4 points, resulting image:
[image]

Using Quartz, I can only specify a rectangle to do this. However, i might not have a perfect rectangle all the time, so what's the best way to do this? 
Thanks

Comment: You could use masks and paths, but how are you handling rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about to use OpenGL "Render to texture" technique? Use those 4 points as input texture coordinates and render straight rectangle to the output texture.